# Memory leak due to many instances of class org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem

Tags: java, memory-leaks, wildfly

I've upgrade my application:
Spring, Spring Security: 3.2.10.RELEASE -> 5.0.7.RELEASE
Hibernate: 4.2.0.Final -> 5.2.17.Final

We use WildFly15.0.1.Final and after upgrade we have a memory leak.
Here is the report of MAT:

```
1 860 instances of "org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem", loaded by "org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0x6c2c43270" occupy 206 395 072 (39,92 %) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]", loaded by "<system class loader>"
```

There are no leaks when we deploy the same application (after upgrade) on WildFly10. Perhaps, problem is not in application but in WildFly itself.
We've try to change WF settings and even increased its memory (yes, not the best solution, but...) - no effect. Could someone point out where the problem is? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem was in SpringSession version. It was solved by changing it from 2.0.2 to 2.1.8.